Hope you can recommend me some books about building mechanical options trading systems
I have some basic understanding of CTA and am quite familiar with options pricing theory. I am interested in learning about books that discuss the use of options tools to construct mechanical trading systems. Ideally, the strategies described by the authors should be quantitative and programmable.Thanks very much.

Asking for a "mechanical" scheme puts me in mind of the MONIAC hydraulic computer for simulating economies.
